# Project Compiles in Netbeans but not using MAKE

Tags: c++, netbeans, makefile, mingw

I have a project that compiles fine in netbeans using MinGW/MSYS but when calling make if fails. Of note is that the first 7 lines are identical. However, NetBeans calling *make* succeeds and calling *make* from the command prompt fails. Any ideas?

**Netbeans** output:

```
    ""make.exe"" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
    make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/d/Source/Project/Project.System'
    "make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/libproject.system.a
    make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/d/Source/Project/Project.System'
    mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src
    rm -f build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/Version.o.d
    g++.exe    -c -g -Iinc -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/Version.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/Version.o src/Version.cpp
    mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src
    rm -f build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/Process.o.d
    g++.exe    -c -g -Iinc -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/Process.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/Process.o src/Process.cpp
    mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src
    rm -f build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/Environment.o.d
    g++.exe    -c -g -Iinc -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/Environment.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/Environment.o src/Environment.cpp
    c:\mingw\bin\ar.exe: creating dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/libProject.system.a
    mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
    rm -f dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/libProject.system.a
    ar -rv dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/libProject.system.a build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/Version.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/Process.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/Environment.o 
    a - build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/Version.o
    a - build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/Process.o
    a - build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/Environment.o
    ranlib dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/libProject.system.a
    make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/d/Source/Project/Project.System'
    make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/d/Source/Project/Project.System'
```

**Make all** output:

```
    ""make.exe"" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
    make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/d/Source/Project/Project.System'
    "make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/libproject.system.a
    make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/d/Source/Project/Project.System'
    mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src
    rm -f build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/Version.o.d
    g++.exe    -c -g -Iinc -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/Version.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/Version.o src/Version.cpp
    g++.exe: no input files
    make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/Version.o] Error 1
    make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/d/Source/Project/Project.System'
    make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
    make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/d/Source/Project/Project.System'
    "make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Comment: netbeans uses make to compile, so.... Are you using it well?

Comment: That is the primary source of my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

> g++.exe    -c -g -Iinc -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/Version.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/Version.o src/Version.cpp
>
> g++.exe: no input files

Where do you launch your make all command from ? looks like g++ does not find find "src/Version.cpp".

Comment: I launch it from the project directory where the Makefile is located (i.e. D:/Source/Project/Project.System). The src directory is under system and Version is in that (i.e. D:/Source/Project/Project.System/src/Version.cpp). It also does this for all projects (there are 7 projects I'm attempting to build... 5 static libraries and 2 applications).

Comment: Do you have a Debug subfolder with a src folder there ?
Like: build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src, 
I would launch make all in D:/Source/Project/Project.System/build/Debug/MinGW-Windows

Comment: No, I do not. All the source is the src folder in the project folders (e.g. Project.LibName/src or Project.App.AppName/src) and all the headers are in an inc folder (e.g. Project.LibName/inc or Project.App.AppName/inc). The inc folder is included in the make file's call to g++ (-Iinc) so it should be able to find the header files. However, it appears to be unable to find the Version.cpp file itself.